# Understanding the derivation of equation 1.2 in Tom Banks's book of "Modern Quantum Field Theory". A source is also a sink

Tags: quantum-field-theory, fourier-transform, antimatter

The book "Modern Quantum Field Theory" by Tom Banks recites in equation 1.1 a probability amplitude for a particle to be produced at $x$, then propagate freely from $x$ to $y$, where it is absorbed:

$$A_{AE}=\int d^{4}x d^{4}y\left \langle x \left | \exp (-iH(x^{0} - y^{0}) ) \right | y \right \rangle J_{A} (x)) J_{E} (y).\tag{1.1}$$

This equation is clear. Then in the next equation, 1.2, the first equation is turned into:

$$A_{AE}=\int d^{4}x d^{4}y J_{A} (x)) J_{E} (y) \int d^{3}p \left | \left \langle 0  |  p \right \rangle   \right |^{2} \exp (-ip(x - y) ) .\tag{1.2}$$

I do not understand how the last integral in equation 1.2 is derived from equation 1.1. This equation is then used to show that an emission source is also an absorption source (a sink).  A detailed derivation and explanation would be greatly appreciated.

P.S. Based upon the suggestion in the comments below, here is my attempt at a derivation. However, in the end, it is wrong.

First,

$$\left \langle x  |  p \right \rangle = \exp (ip\cdot (x))$$
$$\left \langle p  |  y \right \rangle = \exp (-ip\cdot (y))$$
$$\left \langle p  |  p \right \rangle = 1$$

and $$E = \sqrt{\vec{p}^{2}+m^{2}}$$ and that $$H |   p  \rangle = E_{p} |   p  \rangle$$

Plugging in two copies of the momentum basis, as suggested,

$$A_{AE}=\int d^{4}x d^{4}y J_{A} (x)) J_{E} (y) \int d^{3}p \left \langle x  |  p \right \rangle \langle p  | \exp (-iE_{p}  (x^{0} - y^{0}))|  p \rangle \left \langle p  |  y \right \rangle $$

$$A_{AE}=\int d^{4}x d^{4}y J_{A} (x)) J_{E} (y) \int d^{3}p  \exp (-ip\cdot (x - y))$$

and thus I am missing the bit,

$$\left | \left \langle 0  |  p \right \rangle   \right |^{2}$$

from the given result,

$$A_{AE}=\int d^{4}x d^{4}y J_{A} (x)) J_{E} (y) \int d^{3}p \left | \left \langle 0  |  p \right \rangle   \right |^{2} \exp (-ip\cdot (x - y))$$,

and likely a sign problem in the exponent too.

Corrections are earnestly solicited.

Comment: Looks to me like you could insert two resolutions of the identity in terms of momentum eigenstates, one between $|y\rangle$ and $H$ and the other between $\langle y|$ and $H$. Then, act with $H$ on the momentum eigenstates, use the fact that $\langle p|p'\rangle = \delta (p-p')$, and you should be there. Probably there's a change of variables in there somewhere, too.

Comment: Indeed this seems puzzling to me, since for a free field the vacuum is orthogonal to all 1-particle states, so $\langle 0 | p \rangle = 0$. Answering this probably requires a bit more information on exactly what the vacuum state is and possibly what the Lagrangian is.